# find the lowest absolute sum of elements from an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I try to understand a solution from a problem in the Codility provided below,

For a given array A of N integers and a sequence S of N integers from the set {−1, 1}, we define val(A, S) as follows:

```
val(A, S) = |sum{ A[i]*S[i] for i = 0..N−1 }|
```

(Assume that the sum of zero elements equals zero.)

For a given array A, we are looking for such a sequence S that minimizes val(A,S).

Write a function:

```
class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
```

that, given an array A of N integers, computes the minimum value of val(A,S) from all possible values of val(A,S) for all possible sequences S of N integers from the set {−1, 1}.

For example, given array:

```
  A[0] =  1
  A[1] =  5
  A[2] =  2
  A[3] = -2
```

your function should return 0, since for S = [−1, 1, −1, 1], val(A, S) = 0, which is the minimum possible value.

Assume that:

```
N is an integer within the range [0..20,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [−100..100].
Complexity:
```

expected worst-case time complexity is O(N*max(abs(A))2);
expected worst-case space complexity is O(N+sum(abs(A))) (not counting the storage required for input arguments).

I have the solution that I'm trying to understand for the last few hours.

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {

        int N = A.length;

        int sum = 0;
        int max = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

            A[i] = Math.abs(A[i]);
            sum += A[i];

            max = Math.max(A[i], max);
        }


        int[] counts = new int[max + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            counts[A[i]] += 1;
        }

        int[] Total = new int[sum + 1];

        Arrays.fill(Total, -1);
        Total[0] = 0;

        // Segment I
        for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {

            if (counts[i] > 0) {

                for (int j = 0; j <= sum; j++) {

                    // j th index is zero or positive
                    if (Total[j] >= 0) {
                        Total[j] = counts[i];
                    }
                    // (i-j) th index is positive
                    else if ((j - i) >= 0 && Total[j - i] > 0) {
                        Total[j] = Total[j - i] - 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        int result = sum;

        // Segment II
        for (int i = 0; i < sum / 2 + 1; i++) {

            // i- th index if zero or positive
            // BODMAS_RULE = {Brackets, Orders, Division, Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction}
            if (Total[i] >= 0) {
                result = Math.min(result, sum - 2 * i);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

If anyone can explain whats going on in the last 2 segments of the loops, it will be very helpful.  All I look for a brief explanation within few lines of text.

### UPADTE

I would like to understand why do we use conditions in the for loop of the first segment. Besides, why do we iterate till the `sum / 2 + 1` in the second for loop. Thank you.

Comment: Good explanation here: https://codility.com/media/train/solution-min-abs-sum.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make  sum with required property, you can find subset of array A with sum as close as possible to half of overall sum.

It is kind of [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) `subset sum problem` and might be solved with dynamic programming approach  using additional array with dimension corresponding to the overall sum (note array `Total`).

Note that solution from the question deals with positive numbers only, so you have to modify it for using negative  numbers (like your example `A[3] = -2`).

This code makes array `total` of length `sum+1` and holds counts for every value in array `counts`.

At the first stage code fills total table with non-nengative entries for all possible sums. Consider simple set value:count `(2:3; 3:2)`.
First round fills entries 0,2,4,6 with values 3,2,1,0. 
Second round changes all non-negative entries by number of threes and
builds decreasing sequences for chains from non-negative entries (for example, `4--> 4+3 ->4+6`). After that we have total array `[2,-1,2,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,0,-1,0]` with negative entries (impossible sums) at 1,11. Note that such approach does not store information - what items have been used to make every possible sum, so you have to make more modifications.

Comment: Ok, I was trying to understand the provided note since and it still doesn't make much sense. Would you mind to elaborate on the answer?

Comment: But shown code already uses dynamic programming - it fills Total array (segment 1) then finds the closest (to half-sum) filled entry (segment 2)

Comment: Do you understand that subset-sum problem is equivalent to your task?

Comment: Yes, but still it doesn't help me. It's already kind that you pointed me in the right direction. I would really appreciate if you can take time to write an elaborate answer. Thank you.

Comment: Atleast why do we use these conditions?

`if (Total[j] >= 0) {
                        Total[j] = counts[i];
                    }

                    /*
                     * (i-j) th index is positive
                     * */
                    else if ((j - i) >= 0 && Total[j - i] > 0) {
                        Total[j] = Total[j - i] - 1;
                    }` in the first segment.

Comment: You can make "paper debug run" - fill table on the paper for some simple input. I gave an example.